# swagger example response not respecting nested allOf

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

When using the following swagger, the resulting endpoint has an example response that doesn't align with what I believe the swagger (and the models) dictate.

The swagger:

```
components:
  examples: {}
  headers: {}
  parameters: {}
  requestBodies: {}
  responses: {}
  schemas:
    SubSubData:
      type: object
      properties:
        subSubDataProp:
          type: string
    SubData:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SubSubData'
        - type: object
          properties:
            subDataProp:
              type: string
    Data:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SubData'
        - type: object
          properties:
            dataProp:
              type: string
    ExampleResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        data:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Data'
info:
  title: __PROJECT_NAME__
  version: 1.0.0
  description: |
    Add your Swagger description here.
  license:
    name: ISC
  contact:
    name: Me
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /example:
    get:
      operationId: GetData
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Ok
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ExampleResponse'
      security: []
```

The expected response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "dataProp": "string",
    "subDataProp": "string",
    "subSubDataProp": "string"
  }
}
```

Actual:

```
{
  "data": {
    "dataProp": "string"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Or is this a bug in the swagger ui/openapi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in Swagger UI:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5972

The workaround is to move `paths` before `components`.

Comment: That fixed it! That is quite the strange bug and strange that that helps, but thank you!